# Display last selected item in dropdown box in JS

Tags: javascript, php, database, drop-down-menu

I need my selection box to display the last selected item from db after user submits form in JS. Below is my code. The JS correctly shows the options from db. After submission the selection box reverts back to the first item and not selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON("getCompany.php", success = function(data)
{
    var options = "Select Company";

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        options += "<option value='" + data[i].Value + "'>" + data[i].Company + "</option>";
    }

    $("#slctCom").append(options);

    $("#slctCom").change();
});

});
```

Comment: do you reload the page when submitting?

Comment: you can add a click event for when the user selects the item and set the value of the drop-down box to the new "selected" item.

Comment: Please create a fiddle and add HTML too, this way we can fork and edit it to provide answers.

Comment: @veggirice how do I accomplish this?